# VS2010 confuses System.Xml.XmlElement with System.Xml.Linq.XElement?

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I have created a WCF service with one method which returns a `System.Xml.XmlElement`:

**Interface:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    XmlElement Execute(...);
}
```

**Service:**

```
public XmlElement Execute(...)
{
    XmlNode node = ...;

    return (XmlElement)node;
}
```

When I try to access the service deployed on my server

```
WCFServiceClient service = new WCFServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IWCFService");
XmlElement node = service.Execute(...);
```

I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlElement'

Searching my service solution, I cannot see any reference to `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`. Is it wrong of me to expect a `System.Xml.XmlElement` or is VS 2010 fooling around with me?

Comment: Try calling the service using the wcftestclient.exe. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Raj: This is not possible since the `wcftestclient` does not support `System.Xml.XmlElement`. But funny enough it does not mention anything about `System.Xml.Linq.XmlElement`.

Comment: See if this post helps : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2f29bdab-a3ab-41b9-980a-692e7bb7e133

Comment: @Raj: Thanks for your suggestion. Even though very possible, this wasn't my issue.

Answer (score 21):

What I have found works the best and easiest for me is to right-click on the service reference and then click on "Configure Service Reference".  Once in the dialog box for this at the bottom you will see 2 radio buttons that say "Reuse types in **all** referenced assemblies" or "Reuse types in **specified** referenced assemblies".  Click on the 2nd option for 'specified assemblies'.  The listbox will then be enabled and you can check all assemblies and leave *System.Xml.Linq* **unchecked**.  This way every time you update the service reference you will get the expected results and this will be stored in the configuration of the client.

Answer (score 5):

1) Remove the system.xml.linq reference from your client
2) Update your service reference
3) The re-generated Reference.cs file will now reference XmlElement instead of XElement

Answer (score -1):

I hate to answer my own question, but here it goes:

As far as I can see, the `System.Xml.XmlElement` CAN be used as a return type for a WCF service. The `DataContractSerializer` used by default in WCF does [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx) this type and thus it shouldn't be necessary to use the `XmlSerializer`.

However my problem has nothing to do with serializing, but thanks to **Raj Kaimal** for suggesting this possibility.

I followed the [WCF tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx) given by Microsoft, which tells you to add the WCF service as a **Service Reference** when you want to use the service. This seems to be okay in VS2008, but when switching to VS2010 this approach [changes the return type](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/6440cfb9-c3d5-4d5d-8c47-4f4103fb9c84) from `System.Xml.XmlElement` to the (newer?) `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`. To solve this, you need to add the service as a **Web Reference** instead.

Comment: This is not an accurate answer. Your service reference was generated by downloading the XML schema that's in the WSDL. Apparently, your schema has a few places where it accepts arbitrary XML. When a client consumes such a service, the client is likely to choose something like XmlElement or XElement as the return type.

Comment: @John: The answer is as accurate as I can make it - atleast at present time. I'm still in the earliest state of using WCF (and XML), and my answer seem to work for me. It is nowhere near a bullit proof answer - I know - and any edits are more than welcome. Thanks for your attention and comment :)

Comment: here's an experiment: create a data contract class. Add a method to it. Return it from a service operation. Consume it on the client. See if the method exists on the client. Unless you use the "share types" feature, the method won't be there - only what can be passed by the WSDL.

Comment: @John: Thanks for your comment. I haven't got the time right now to do the experiment, but I will be required to address this problem later on - thus I will return to this in the future.