# when WCF method returns XmlElement , the client sees XElement returned?

Tags: xml, wcf, xelement

i return an xmlElement from a WCf method.
when i do a service reference in the client, the same method is returning XElement instead of XmlElement. 
i tried everything: updating the service reference, making a new service reference, but it doesn't help.

This is my client:

```
ServiceReference1.BasicServiceClient basicWCfClient = new ServiceReference1.BasicServiceClient();
        XmlElement xmlelement =  basicWCfClient.GetData(5); 
        basicWCfClient.Close();
```

i get an error : 
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlElement'"

when the method in the server side:

```
 public XmlElement GetData(int value)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml("<msg><node1>Hello</node1><node2>World</node2><request_params><mynode>More</mynode></request_params></msg>");
        XmlElement xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
        return xmlElement;
     }
```

and the interface:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IBasicService
{

    [OperationContract]       
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData?value={value}")] // Add support for HTTP GET Requests
    XmlElement GetData(int value);}
```

what is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. Client doesn't know which .NET type has been used and service reference informs it only that any XML can be returned. It takes XML and provides it as XElement. It is build in behavior and I think it was chosen by MS because of newer and more comfortable API. Why do you need the method to return XmlElement?

Comment: my test client is indeed compiled in Framework 3.5 but the other company (the true client) wont have Framework 3.5, it works with framework 2.0 and it won't recognise XElement because XElement is Framework 3.5. but on second thought, will my WCF service return XmlElement when the true client (with framework 2.0 environment) will create a service reference? it won't return Xelement right ?

Comment: just tried the same reference from VS2005 in framework 2.0 and it indeed returns Xmlelement. The framework environment was the problem, thanks!

Comment: First of all when you consume the service in .NET 2.0 you will not be able to use Add service reference because .NET 2.0 doesn't support WCF. You will have to use Add web reference and it will use only .NET 2.0 types.

Comment: He may be using primarily 2.0 with some of the 3.0 libraries (there was a 3.0 release), which is basically WCF.  I've seen that before, so when he says 2.0, he means 3.0, which is 2.0 + WCF (and maybe some other stuff, but I'm not sure on what else was there).

Answer (score 13):

Go to `Configure Service Reference` and check `Reuse types in referenced assemblies`

Then check `System.Xml` if you want `XmlElement` or `System.Xml.Linq` if you want `XElement`

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855597)

Comment: Does not work for me. I tried to remove service reference and create again. I also tried to remove System.Xml reference and leave only System.Xml.Linq. However, it still uses XmlNode.

Comment: Did you uncheck the system.xml box or did you just remove reference from the project?

Comment: Tried both ways. I assume that WCF tries to use XElement not for all services. One service has soap, soap12 and http bindings - System.Xml is used. Another has soap and soap12 - System.Xml.Linq.

Comment: BTW, it works in another direction - I can use System.Xml for both services. So, you answer helped me. Thank you.