# XmlDocument.DocumentElement missing Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, namespaces

I have a strange problem where I cant seem to get the namespaces right, when sending a XMLElement to a WCF service.

The XMLElement comes from a XMLDocument which is loaded from disk like so:

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load(new XmlTextReader("C:\\Temp\\Test.xml"));
```

The XML contains these namespaces:

```
<Root ID="0bb2cc41-57d0-4fc7-93e9-4cbddc8f216b" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:somenamespace:2009.07.03">
```

However when I use the WCF service like this

```
vsLightKlient.SendRequest(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
```

I can see that the WCF service is only receiving

```
<Root ID="8aa6d535-f448-47b6-b982-c4b9b50556aa" xmlns="urn:somenamespace:2009.07.03>
```

This is a problem because I am signing the original `XMLDocument` with the extra namespaces. When the extra namespaces are removed, the signature does not match what I send and the verification fails

How do I get the `xmlDoc.DocumentElement` to actually send all of the namespaces?

Comment: I don't seem to be having the same issue. I reproduced your code, while I found that serialization changed the order of the namespaces it didn't remove them. Do you know what is happening within vsLightKlient.SendRequest? Also, how are you producing the XML string from the XmlElement object within the service?

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you so much for testing and replying. I don't have access to the WCF service as it is being supplied to me, but I was able to send XElements instead, and this fixes the problem for me. See the answer for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this tip:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337548/1005134

I was able to force the WCF client to accept a XElement. When I get the payload I send back, I can see that all my namespaces is present. Not sure where the error was with the DocumentElement though.

Best,

Andreas