# Why Web Service is converting XmlDocument parameter to System.XML.Linq.XElement Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, web-services

IDE: VS 2010 c# .net 4.0

I a creating a simple web service which will take XMLDocument as Parameter

```
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


  public void ReceiveXML(XmlDocument  xDoc, string strXMLFileName)
    {
        XMLReceiver.Receive(xDoc, strXMLFileName);
    }
}
```

When I ran this service and added to ProjectB using add service reference, and went to reference file than I found

```
 public void ReceiveXML(System.Xml.Linq.XElement xDoc, string strXMLFileName) {
       ReceiveXMLRequest inValue = new ReceiveXMLRequest();
        inValue.Body = new ReceiveXMLRequestBody();
        inValue.Body.xDoc = xDoc;
        inValue.Body.strXMLFileName = strXMLFileName;

    }
```

here I am not getting as I have written XmlDocument type parameter to receive why refrence.cs file is created function with System.Xml.Linq.XElement xDoc paramter instead of XMLDocument type..?

I am trying to pass abc.xml file to webService by loading it in XMLDocument xdoc.load(strABCContent);

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741490/when-wcf-method-returns-xmlelement-the-client-sees-xelement-returned

Answer (score 1):

When you publish a WCF service, you are decoupling the actual implementation of the service through an interface, described by `WSDL`, which is technology agnostic. WSDL won't be able to specify that the content is a .Net `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and will instead specify an abstraction ([`xs:any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043(v=vs.110).aspx) if I remember correctly)

This is why, when consuming the service (even from the same .Net technology stack), you will get a potentially different client interface (as with `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`).

You can replace your `XmlDocument.Load` with a Linq 2 Xml [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Client:

```
var myXDocument = XDocument.Load(strABCContent)
```

And pass it to the service reference proxy method, `ReceiveXML`